# Python: how to pass 3 columns in data frame as 3 separate arguments in function and iterate through the column values

Tags: python, function, loops, dataframe, iteration

I have the following python data frame with columns listed below:
This data frame is stored to the variable WSI_Hourly

```
Date    Rain (in)            
1/5     2           
1/6     0          
1/7     7   
1/8     10    
1/9     13   
1/10    11   
1/11    1
```

I am trying to write a function that creates a new column specifying the dynamic range bucket the "Rain" values fall under.  Please see  **desired output table** :

```
Date   Rain     Rain_Range    
1/5    2        0-5 inches
1/6    0        0-5 inches
1/7    7        6-10 inches
1/8    10       6-10 inches
1/9    13       11-15 inches
1/10   11       11-15 inches
1/11   1        0-5 inches
```

Below is my function:

```
def precip(df, min_value, max_value, desc):
    if(min_value < max_value):
        for i, m in df.iterrows():
            if (m['Rain'] >= min_value) & (m['Rain'] <= max_value):
                df.set_value(i, 'Rain_Range', desc)

precip(WSI_Hourly, min_value, max_value, desc)
```

Because I want to dynamically set what the 'Rain_Range' values are, I want to pass the following data frame through the function denoting the min_value, max_value, and desc arguments.

Please see data frame table below:

```
min_value   max_value   desc      
0           5           0-5 inches   
6           10          6-10 inches    
11          15          11-15 inches
```

My QUESTION IS: How do I pass the min_value, max_value, and desc columns in the data frame above into my function as arguments to get my  **desired output table** ?

*Any help on this is greatly appreciated

Comment: use `pd.cut` to make it categorical

Comment: thanks for the quick response; I don't quite understand what you mean...would you mind explaining in a little more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip your function, using `pd.cut`.

Some data:

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

dat=StringIO('''Date    Rain(in)            
1/5     2           
1/6     0          
1/7     7   
1/8     10    
1/9     13   
1/10    11   
1/11    1   ''')

cuts = StringIO('''min_value   max_value   desc      
0           5           0-5inches   
6           10          6-10inches    
11          15          11-15inches''')
df = pd.read_csv(dat, delim_whitespace = True)
cuts = pd.read_csv(cuts, delim_whitespace = True)
```

Now we 'cut' using the `pd.cut` function, using bins and labels from your 'cuts' data frame:

```
df['Rain_Range'] = pd.cut(df['Rain(in)'],\
        bins = pd.concat([cuts.min_value[:1]-1,cuts.max_value]),\
        labels = cuts.desc)
```

which gives:

```
Date    Rain(in)    Rain_Range
1/5     2   0-5inches
1/6     0   0-5inches
1/7     7   6-10inches
1/8     10  6-10inches
1/9     13  11-15inches
1/10    11  11-15inches
1/11    1   0-5inches
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are looking for, you want the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function.

```
def f(x,y,z):
    for a,b,c in zip(x,y,z):
        print(a,b,c)

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [10, 20, 30, 40]
z = [100, 200, 300, 400]

f(x,y,z)
```

The data is passed as columns of data, the `zip` function iterates over all three columns simultaneously, returning an iterable of tuples, which you can unpack as the loop indices of the `for` loop.

Comment: thank you..let me give this a try; I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: this is not quite what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

As @jeremycg suggested in the comment, use `pd.cut()`:

```
pd.cut(df["Rain"], 
       [-0.001, 5, 10, 15], # Bin boundaries
       labels=["0-5 inches", "6-10 inches", "11-15 inches"] # Bin labels
      )

# Result:
# 0      0-5 inches
# 1      0-5 inches
# 2     6-10 inches
# 3     6-10 inches
# 4    11-15 inches
# 5    11-15 inches
# 6      0-5 inches
# Name: Rain, dtype: category
# Categories (3, object): [0-5 inches < 6-10 inches < 11-15 inches]
```

Comment: thanks for the "cut" info above.  unfortunately, I do need to put it in a function because everything has to be functionalized in my code so it can be called by a high level 'group function call' in the end.  Any thoughts on how to do the same thing inside a function?

Comment: Sure. Just define a function that takes `df` as the parameter and adds a column to it.